# Custom module visible only for one user

Tags: 7, users, caching

EDIT:

14:38 PM Amsterdam :P

Nice to see that good people help !...

What I trying to do:

This is the whole prototype code.

```
function oleg_menu() {


    $items=array();
    $items['user/%user/pgacademy/tests'] = array(
        'title' => 'OLEG',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('oleg_nameform',1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}


function oleg_nameform($form, &$form_state,$accoundID) {
     $form=array();
     dpm($accauntID);
     return $form;
}
```

The page even doesn't appear...
Can someone explain me why it fails,or what could be the problem ?
Oleg

Comment: Actually what you are trying to achieve. could you please elaborate more?

Comment: using `$items['user/%user/foo/bar]` should work..
You **must** clear the caches everytime.

Answer (score 1):

What indrock says in the comments is right, you should be using a placeholder like `%user`.

But you'll also need to pass the argument through to the form callback like so:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/foo/bar'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Title',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_nameform', 1),
    'access callback' =>array('user_is_logged_in'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The signature for `my_module_nameform()` would be:

```
function my_module_nameform($form, &$form_state, $account)
```

`user_is_logged_in()` doesn't accept any parameters so there's no need for the `access arguments`. Again as indrock says, clear the caches whenever you make a change to the hook implementation.

Comment: I have edited the post ... :) take a new look...

Comment: Did you clear Drupal's caches after making the change? And by 'not appear' do you mean that a new tab doesn't appear on the user account?

Comment: Hi Clive, I flushed the cache..I am doing it every time.

The tab is there...But it displays something different,from the module "Panels".

Still...if I do global $user and $user->uid it works very fine for a single user :(....

I am really confused

Comment: Ah, it sounds like panels is doing a number on the page. I can't help with that I'm afraid, I've never used it. The code above is 100% definitely the right way to do it; it might be worth asking a question to the effect of "why does panels stop this code working?"

Comment: Also its not the user id but rather the fully loaded user object that will passed through to your form function...could that be causing a problem? If you don't want that to be the case, just change the menu path to `user/%/foo/bar`. That will pass the account id rather than the user object

Comment: Some weeks later....
The panels were the problem.
What I did as a workaround was, converting the whole form to a block,which is called from the panel itself. I hope this can help someone.

Thanks Again Clive.!!!!